# Fluent NHibernate - ¿How can i map 3 parent tables to the same child table?

Tags: c#, oracle, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have 3 parent tables pointing to the same child table.
I need to write the mapping.
I've tried with "HasManyToMany" but i only achieved inserted two fields into the child table instead of the 3 fields.

```
HasManyToMany<Entity_A>(x => x.Entities_B).Table("CHILD_TABLE")
.ParentKeyColumn("A_ID")
.ChildKeyColumn("B_ID")
.Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

Each of the 3 mappings have 2 of these blocks "HasManyToMany" everyone pointing to "CHILD_TABLE"

Comment: Please paste whatever code you have already tried.

Comment: done, thnks @codeepic